# How to add a row of data to the TreeListView and then add a subdata to the row?

Tags: objectlistview, treelistview

How to add a row of data to the TreeListView control and then add a subdata to the row?

[image]

[TreeListViewControlTest_c#2010.zip (download link - Dropbox)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7robkcdij68ty7h/TreeListViewControlTest_c%232010.zip?dl=0)